# Forbidden (403) when requesting a page via python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I want to request [this](https://www.bizportal.co.il/realestates/quote/generalview/373019) via python3.

This is the code:

```
import requests
bizportal_company_url = "https://www.bizportal.co.il/realestates/quote/generalview/373019"
self.page = requests.get(self.bizportal_company_url)
```

and I get:

```
<Response [403]>
```

When I add `verify=False` to the get command, I get:

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
<Response [403]>
```

How can I fix it? When I access the url there is no password or anything.

Comment: Are you sure the site opens in web browser?

Comment: @Ava I can, yes. Why, you can't?

Comment: no I can't. :) Not atleast with the link that you have in the code.

Comment: Try adding appropriate http headers while fetching the contents.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When you open the site on your browser, check what http headers are used while your browser initiate the request.

Comment: How do I check it?

Comment: By going into the network tabs. You'll find that in web dev tools in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing a few things in your code.

Try this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get("https://www.bizportal.co.il", headers=headers)

url = "https://www.bizportal.co.il/realestates/quote/generalview/373019"
print(session.get(url, headers=headers).status_code)
```

This should print:

```
200
```

Which basically means the request has been successful.

Comment: This doesnt work on google colab, I get timeout. Do you know why?